# How to deploy an SQL Compact Edition database file (.sdf) in the AppData folder? Connection string?

Tags: sql, visual-studio, sql-server-ce, connection-string, setup-deployment

I'm planning to deploy my DB file in the `Users\CurrentUserName\AppData` folder, because default User Account Control settings restrict write access to the Program Files directory where my program is installed.
First question - is this correct?

So far, I've created a custom folder, set the DefaultLocation property to `[LocalAppDataFolder][ProductName]`, and put the .sdf file in that folder.
This works in Windows 7, but it doesn't seem to work in Windows XP - I can't find any sign of it being deployed anywhere.

So where and how should I deploy the DB file?

I'm also unsure how to set the connection string to the `[LocalAppDataFolder]` location - any suggestions?

**Edit:**  The application is a WinForms application which will be downloaded from a website and installed using the installer created with Setup Project.

Comment: What kind of app is it?? ASP.NET ? Winforms? Console? Service?

Comment: Winforms, sorry for not specifying it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me:

```
string fileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "SqlCe35AddinStore.sdf");

string connString = string.Format("Data Source={0};", fileName);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It really helped. So, in your opinion, AppData folder is the one in which to save the database file? Again, thanks for the idea.